# Mapping Maybes with defaults

Tags: functional-programming, elm

Im new to Elm and fp in general so I am trying to figure this out

I am trying to decode a Json which may have 2 optional fileds "username" and "password" amongst others

I successfully decode the structure into the following type

```
type alias Req = 
    { ...
    , username : Maybe String
    , password: Maybe String
    }
```

Also I have other types

```
type alias BA = 
     { username : String
     , password : String
     }

type alias sBA = Maybe BA
```

Now I would like to have a function getsBa such that I can do the following

```
getsBA : Req -> sBA
...

a : Req
a = { ...
     , username = Just "test"
     , password = Nothing
     }

getsBA a == Just { username = "test", password = "" }

b = { ...
     , username = Nothing
     , password = Nothing
     }
 getsBA b = Nothing

c : Req
c = { ...
     , username = Nothing
     , password = Just "123"
     }

getsBA a == Just { username = "", password = "123" }


d : Req
d = { ...
     , username = Just "test"
     , password = Just "123"
     }

getsBA a == Just { username = "test", password = "123" }
```

How can I think about such a solution in terms of FP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type alias Creds = (Maybe String, Maybe String)
f :: Req -> Creds
f r = (r.username, r.password)

g :: Creds -> sBA
g c = 
  case c of
    (Nothing, Nothing) -> Nothing
    (Nothing, Just p) -> Just {username = "", password = p}
    (Just u, Nothing) -> Just {username = u, password = ""}
    (Just u, Just p) -> Just {username = u, password = p}

getsBA = g << f
```

f is the field extractor, g manipulates those values and getsBA is the composition of these two (extract fields and then manipulate them).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to @duggi's answer which makes use of `Maybe.withDefault` to reduce repetition in the code:

```
getsBA : Req -> SBA
getsBA { username, password } =
    case ( username, password ) of
        ( Nothing, Nothing ) ->
            Nothing

        _ ->
            Just <| BA (Maybe.withDefault "" username) (Maybe.withDefault "" password)
```